# How would I go about making a seaborn categorical Plot in d3.js or the recharts library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, recharts

[This is the graph I want to replicate for a react application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQhg3.png)

[This is the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6adJh.png)

I could not find any implement using the "recharts" library online. If it's not possible or feasible with recharts, and solution with d3.js would be great.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A google search for “d3 violin plot” shows multiple examples, e. g. this one http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/92929960988a8935d907e39e60ea8417